# How can I share state between 'Queueable' executions?

Tags: apex, callout, queueable-apex

I am developing a Queueable class to send data to an external system via HTTP callouts. I am planning to chain this class to call itself multiple times, until all records have been processed, or until I hit some limit for re-queue to prevent forever running retries. Once all records have been synced (or the re-queue limit has been reached), I will call the next Queueable class in the chain.

My initial thought is that I'd use a `static` variable to track the queue depth, but this won't work because `static` variables live inside the current transaction only, so I need some way to share state between Queueable executions to track my current queue depth.

One thing I thought of was to persist this value to the database, but I don't like it because there could be concurrency issues if jobs were to overlap for some reason.

Has anyone else solved this problem, and if so how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard approach for this is to pass state via the constructor

```
class MyQueueable {
  Object state;
  public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
    // do work using state up to the point where you need to chain queueable
    state = ... // set new state
    System.enqueueJob(state);
  }
  /*  constructor */
  public MyQueueable(Object state) {this.state = state;}
}
```

I used an `Object` for state here as a placeholder but you can make it whatever is convenient for you like a collection of Ids (e.g. `Id[] work`)

Comment: Constructor, of course! I was clearly over thinking this. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 11):

A class calling itself can enqueue itself. No need to construct a new object.

```
public class MyQueueable implements Queueable {
  Integer counter = 0;
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    // If we have not yet run five times...
    if(counter++ < 5) {
      // Go again!
      System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a special use case. If you need to call a different queueable and maintain state, you can use a state variable to pass information between contexts, as stated by cropredy in their [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/349794).

Comment: i should have thought of this (so-to-speak)